# Python API - Influxdb - When I tried to connect to database and fetch the list of existing db, influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 401:

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb

```
>>> from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', '<Password>')
>>> client.get_list_database()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/<USername>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 704, in get_list_database
    return list(self.query("SHOW DATABASES").get_points())
  File "/home/<USername>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 527, in query
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/home/<USername>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 378, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(err_msg, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 401: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Can someone please guide me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, this issue very clear, according to what you wrote as your instructions to connect to InfluxDB and in this line:

> ```py
> client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', '<Password>')
> ```

It seems that you used a sample command to connect to your database(I know it from something like `'<Password>'` as your password to connect to database), and because of this you get 401 error which means your credentials is not true, write these credentials yourself and which are True for your InfluxDB.